# How do you get the Id of the item in CheckListBox

Tags: c#

I have a checkListBox in my windows form application and binded with my database data with SQL. I populate a list of item according to what I select from my comboBox. If I select item 1 from my comboBox, it will display customers' name who is using this item. I want get customers' id according to what I check in my checkListBox.

**Here is how I fill my comboBox**

```
 private void fill_comboBox()
        {
            myConn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Initial Catalog= dbName; Trusted_Connection = True");
            try
            {
                string query = "select itemId, itemName from item_detail";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                myConn.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, myConn);

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                dt.Load(reader);

                DataRow dr;
                dr= dt.NewRow();
                dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "<----------Select an item-------> " };
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

                itemComboBox.DataSource = dr;
                itemComboBox.ValueMember = "itemId";
                itemComboBox.DisplayMember = "itemName";

                fill_customerCheckListBox();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

**Here is how I fill my checkListBox**

```
private void fill_customerCheckListBox()
{
    myConn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Initial Catalog= dbName; Trusted_Connection = True");

    try
    {
        myConn.Open();

        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        myDataSet.CaseSensitive = true;

        string commandString = "select fullName from[customer_detail] as cd LEFT JOIN[item_customer] as ic ON ic.customerId= cd.customerI WHERE ic.itemId= '" + itemCombBox.SelectedValue + "' ";

        myCommand = new SqlCommand();

        myCommand.Connection = myConn;

        myCommand.CommandText = commandString;

        SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;

        myDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "customer_detail");

        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

        DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];

        customerCB.Items.Clear();

        string s = "Select All Customer";

        customer.Items.Add(s);

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in myDataTable.Rows)
        {

            customerCB.Items.Add(dataRow["fullName"]);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I have a praremter for loop that trying to loop through every checked item from my customerCB, but this isn't working. When I am in my debug mode, the code  `DataRow row = (itemChecked as DataRowView).Row;` is causing an exception

> Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

I have no idea how to fix this. Help will be appreciated, thanks

```
 string parameterList = ""; 



foreach (object itemChecked in customerCB.CheckedItems) 
{ 
     DataRow row = (itemChecked as DataRowView).Row; 
     parameterList += (parameterList.Length == 0) ? row[0].ToString() : ", " + row[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: what is `customerCB` ? What are the ValueMember and DIsplay member of it? Is it WinForm or WPF?

Comment: @alekkowalczyk did you actually read my question at all?

Comment: Aren't you setting the ["fullName"] value as the actual item? How can you expect the itemChecked to have the full row then?

Comment: @zaitsman, woops sorry, I posted the wrong for loop, I have updated it

Comment: @DragonBorn Did u tried my solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Following way !!

```
foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
         DataRowView castedItem = itemChecked as DataRowView;
         string fullName= castedItem["fullName"];

    }
```

(OR)  You would need to cast or parse the items to their strongly typed equivalents, or use the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` namespace to use the [DataRowExtensions.Field method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) demonstrated below:

```
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    var row = (itemChecked as DataRowView).Row;
    int id = row.Field<int>("ID");
    string name = row.Field<string>("fullName");

}
```

Comment: I have tried both of your method, it end up the same exception. the second method when the debugger run `var row = (itemChecked as DataRowView).Row;' It jump to exception right away. It can't even execute the code below it

Comment: Also, the first one it said cannot implicitly convert type object to string

Comment: and also I get the castedItem as null

Answer (score 0):

it seems than when you are populating your combobox your are entering `dataRow["fullName"]` therefore this cast `DataRow row = (itemChecked as DataRowView).Row` won't work as `itemChecked` only contains the value of `fullName` and not the row, try adding the dataRow instead.

Comment: what do you mean by adding the dataRow? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Change this `customerCB.Items.Add(dataRow["fullName"]);` for `customerCB.Items.Add(dataRow);` on `fill_customerCheckListBox` method in combination with the answer of @Webruster